# How can i correctly free a struct work_struct allocated with vmalloc

Tags: c, linux, module, vmalloc

I am developing a kernel module for the Linux kernel. Basically, what I need to do is populating /dev with some special char devices. Upon a write operation on such devices, I need to store the message and then make it available to readers after a timeout.
I thought about implementing this with Linux work queues and it works, however, I am forced to allocate dynamic memory with vmalloc() for every write request:

```c
struct delayed_message {
    struct delayed_work delayed_work;
    struct list_head list;
    struct group *group;
    struct message *message;
};

delayed_message = vmalloc(sizeof(struct delayed_message));
if (!delayed_message) {
    printk(KERN_ERR "%s: delayed write error: vmalloc failed on delayed message allocation\n",
           KBUILD_MODNAME);
    ret = -ENOMEM;
    goto free_message_buffer;
}

INIT_DELAYED_WORK(&delayed_message->delayed_work, &publisher_work);
delayed_message->group = group;
delayed_message->message = message;

queue_delayed_work(group->work_queue, &delayed_message->delayed_work, msecs_to_jiffies(group->delay_ms));

// Keep the pointer to the delayed message
spin_lock(&group->delayed_messages_spinlock);
list_add_tail(&delayed_message->list, &group->delayed_messages);
spin_unlock(&group->delayed_messages_spinlock);
```

Is there a safe way to reclaim the memory without interfering with the work queue?

Comment: Is this something where a ring buffer could help?

Comment: I am already keeping track of the delayed_message structs allocations using a list.

Comment: You could always have a pool of "lightly used" structures you can pull from instead of allocating if allocating is proving to be a *measurable performance problem*. This is pretty easy to do if you add a `next` pointer to the structure for this purpose, or for more memory compactness, use a `union` for such a purpose. You could also use `struct message*` with some casting in a pinch.

Comment: Sure, this would work. However, i cannot make any assumption on the number of messages the device receives. If the ring buffer is filled before the first message is delivered then the module starts dropping messages.

Comment: I'd benchmark the allocation cost by over-allocating by a factor of something ridiculous, like 1000x, just to see if it hurts (e.g. 1000 allocations, 1000 frees, then 1 more allocation for "real"). If you don't notice it, forget about it. If it's painful use a linked list approach to store spare structs you can recycle.